# Finding the order of an irreducible polynomial $f$ in $F_3[x]$ of degree 4?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

The technique I am using is based on the long division of $x^e - 1$ (e is to be the order) which is really tiresome. So what the other methods (efficient)?

Comment: In what finite field are you working?

Comment: IOW: it would be easier to read your question, if the question were *in its entirety* in the question body. I first commented on this after having not fully read the title. Keeping key bits only in the title is a common source of confusion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots of your irreducible quartic polynomial $f(x)$ reside in the field $\Bbb{F}_{81}$. The multiplicative group of that field is cyclic of order 80. Therefore the order of your polynomial is a factor of $80$. Because your polynomial does not split into a product quadratics and lower, its order is not a factor of $8$. That leaves $10,16,20,40$ and $80$ as alternatives. If you can check that the order is not a factor of $40$ or $16$, then you can already conclude that it has to be $80$.

But don't do long division. You can reasonably quickly calculate the residue of $x^e$ modulo $f(x)$ by the good ole [square-and-multiply algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: You can also quickly eliminate $16$ as a possibility by factoring
$$x^{16}-1=(x^8-1)(x^8+1).$$ Here $x^8-1$ splits into quadratic factors and lower. But
$$x^8+1=(x^8+4x^4+4)-4x^4=(x^4+2)^2-(2x^2)^2=(x^4-2x^2+2)(x^4+2x^2+2)=(x^4+x^2-1)(x^4-x^2-1).$$